# phpgrid in Laravel 4.1 not working with domain masking

Tags: php, jqgrid, laravel, laravel-4, phpgrid

I'm using Laravel 4.1. I put phpgrid into the vendors directory. Here are my paths using example domains:

Actual file path to website root: `/home/.../htdocs/dashboard/public`

Actual file path to phpgrid: `/home/.../htdocs/dashboard/vendor/phpgrid`

The (example) url to the site is: `http://www.site1.com/dashboard/`

The SERVER_ROOT is set to: `http://www.site1.com/dashboard/vendor/phpgrid`

phpgrid works when I use that domain. The problem is that I want to use a shorter domain with masking. So the url I want to use is something like: `http://dashboard.myotherdomain.com/`, and the virtual host has it pointing to the actual file path to the website root directory above. phpgrid builds the table, but then the AJAX fires and can't get to the `vendor` directory because it is now below the site root of the masked domain. I thought it would use the absolute path, but it doesn't seem to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was with the AJAX calls. AJAX will not let you call a different domain for security reasons, so setting the `SERVER_ROOT` to a different domain than my masked domain was failing (silently btw, blank error message in phpgrid). So I was forced to move the phpgrid files and folders into the webroot and change the `SERVER_ROOT` to a relative path.

A simple fix although I would have preferred to keep the files in the `vendor` directory.